# Dismissing Modally Presented VC and Popping Presenting VC

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a `viewcontroller` embedded in a `navigationcontroller` that pushes another `viewcontroller` onto the stack. This pushed `viewcontroller` has an `embedded viewcontroller` that segues/modally presents a final `viewcontroller`.

On a button click, I am trying to dismiss the final presented `viewcontroller` and pop the present-ing `viewcontroller` and return to the initial state.

Thus far, I've been able to get the dismiss going, but popping does not seem to work in the completion handler of the dismiss.

I've tried printing out the hierarchy, i.e. `self.presentingViewController`, `self.navigationController`, `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController`..., all of which output nil, and am admittedly stuck now on returning to the initial state.

In looking at the view hierarchy, the final presented `viewcontroller` is beneath a `UITransitionView` separate from the rest of the stack I had mentioned earlier..

Any thoughts/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned segues I think [unwind segues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/215/) might help. I built a quick test project and they do indeed function correctly in your scenario.

There is a rather excellent answer in a related SO question [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/542244). A summary of the answer for your particular case is: place the following function in your initial view controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
}
```

You can then directly 'unwind' to that viewcontroller by using Storyboard Segues directly (as in the referenced answer) or programatically via:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToThisViewController", sender: self)
```

Again there's a good article entitled [Working with Unwind Segues Programmatically in Swift](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/) which goes into lots of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
if let nav = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

     self.dismiss(animated:true) {

        nav.popToRootViewController(animated:true)
     }
 }
```